# Update localStorage variable inside a for loop in Javascript

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I am using JSTree to render some of my directories and sub-directories. In the js tree I have checkboxes enabled and when the user is selecting more than 1 checkbox I am disabling the first selection to enable the second selection. The following is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#annotateDirectories").jstree({
        "checkbox": {   
        'tie_selection' : false,        
        'two_state' : true 
    },

    'plugins': ['wholerow', 'search','checkbox', 'sort']
    });

    //control brand selection within annotated directories
    $('#annotateDirectories').on('check_node.jstree uncheck_node.jstree', function(e, data){
            var brandNode = data.instance.get_node(data.selected[1]);
        if(data.instance.get_checked().length>1){
          data.instance.uncheck_node(data.selected[0]);
            if (typeof brandNode.text === "undefined" || typeof brandNode.text === "") {
                alert("select a brand");
            } else {
                localStorage.clear();
                localStorage.setItem('brandNode', brandNode.text);
                show_message("Selected Brand: " +brandNode.text);   
            }
        }
        });
});
```

I am storing the selected brand in localStorage.

In a canvas I am drawing rectangles.  For each drawn rectangle I want to assign the brand name from localStorage.

The following is a part of for loop.

```
function draw_all_region_id() {
  _iris_reg_ctx.shadowColor = "transparent";
  for ( var i = 0; i < _iris_img_metadata[_iris_image_id].regions.length; ++i ) {
    var canvas_reg = _iris_canvas_regions[i];

    var bbox = get_region_bounding_box(canvas_reg);
    var x = bbox[0];
    var y = bbox[1];
    var w = Math.abs(bbox[2] - bbox[0]);
    var brandName = (i+1);
```

Now with `(i+1)` I am able to attach an incremental number to the bounding box.  The problem that I am facing is when I change the

```
var brandName = localStorage.getItem("brandNode");
```

Since this is inside the for loop, for every rectangle it assigns the same name.   Besides, when I draw a new rectangle with a variable name, the names of all the earlier rectangle changes to the new name.

Answer (score 0):

You should store the items in `localStorage` with unique name for each brand, otherwise any new write with same key will overwrite the previous one.

You should be storing the value in the localStorage like following.

```
  localStorage.setItem('brandNode' + uniqueId, brandNode.text);
```

Same key should be used to access it back.

Don't clear the local storage competently like your are doing

```
localStorage.clear();
```

Instead remove the specific item from the `localStorage`